# PHP Sort Multidimensional Array first by Order Array and Second by Ascending Values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array similar to this (small subset):

Small subset:

```
$array[123][2501]['sales_class'] = '2';
$array[123][2501]['option_order'] = '11';
$array[124][2487]['sales_class'] = '2';
$array[124][2487]['option_order'] = '13';
$array[3][2]['sales_class'] = '1';
$array[3][2]['option_order'] = '3';
$array[6][1092]['sales_class'] = '1';
$array[6][1092]['option_order'] = '1';
$array[3][2]['sales_class'] = '1';
$array[3][2]['option_order'] = '3';
$array[21][2296]['sales_class'] = '4';
$array[21][2296]['option_order'] = '1';
$array[111][1447]['sales_class'] = '4';
$array[111][1447]['option_order'] = '2';
```

More realistic:

```
$new_array[1][2422]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[1][2422]['option_order'] = '0';
$new_array[2][1908]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[2][1908]['option_order'] = '4';
$new_array[3][2]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[3][2]['option_order'] = '3';
$new_array[4][5]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[4][5]['option_order'] = '2';
$new_array[5][2436]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[5][2436]['option_order'] = '5';
$new_array[6][1092]['sales_class'] = '1';
$new_array[6][1092]['option_order'] = '1';
$new_array[7][7]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[7][7]['option_order'] = '2';
$new_array[8][11]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[8][11]['option_order'] = '3';
$new_array[21][2296]['sales_class'] = '4';
$new_array[21][2296]['option_order'] = '1';
$new_array[27][2434]['sales_class'] = '13';
$new_array[27][2434]['option_order'] = '0';
$new_array[34][2489]['sales_class'] = '4';
$new_array[34][2489]['option_order'] = '0';
$new_array[47][2055]['sales_class'] = '13';
$new_array[47][2055]['option_order'] = '1';
$new_array[107][1809]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[107][1809]['option_order'] = '7';
$new_array[111][1447]['sales_class'] = '4';
$new_array[111][1447]['option_order'] = '2';
$new_array[112][2446]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[112][2446]['option_order'] = '1';
$new_array[113][2498]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[113][2498]['option_order'] = '4';
$new_array[116][2485]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[116][2485]['option_order'] = '12';
$new_array[118][2472]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[118][2472]['option_order'] = '14';
$new_array[120][2470]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[120][2470]['option_order'] = '9';
$new_array[121][2475]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[121][2475]['option_order'] = '15';
$new_array[122][2476]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[122][2476]['option_order'] = '10';
$new_array[123][2501]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[123][2501]['option_order'] = '11';
$new_array[124][2487]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[124][2487]['option_order'] = '13';
$new_array[126][2509]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[126][2509]['option_order'] = '0';
$new_array[128][2525]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[128][2525]['option_order'] = '6';
$new_array[130][1409]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[130][1409]['option_order'] = '17';
$new_array[162][2548]['sales_class'] = '9';
$new_array[162][2548]['option_order'] = '33';
$new_array[181][2568]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[181][2568]['option_order'] = '5';
$new_array[199][2603]['sales_class'] = '2';
$new_array[199][2603]['option_order'] = '8';
```

I need to be able to first sort by sales_class based on the following dynamically created array:

```
$order_array = array(1, 4, 2);
```

Order for more realistic array above:

```
$new_order = array(1,13,4,2,14,9,3,15,16);
```

Then, secondarily, I need to sort on option_order.

The resulting sorted array would be (for the small subset):

```
Array(
    [6] => Array(
            [1092] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 1
                    [option_order] => 1
                )
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [2] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 1
                    [option_order] => 3
                )
        )
    [21] => Array(
            [2296] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 4
                    [option_order] => 1
                )
        )
    [111] => Array(
            [1447] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 4
                    [option_order] => 2
                )
        )
    [123] => Array(
            [2501] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 2
                    [option_order] => 11
                )
        )

    [124] => Array(
            [2487] => Array(
                    [sales_class] => 2
                    [option_order] => 13
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating another element in the array (sales_class_order) which eliminated the need for a custom order ($order_array). Then I used array_multisort combined with array_combine to restore my keys. The added element allowed for SORT_ASC within array_multisort.

```
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach($array as $first) {
        foreach($first as $second) {
            $sales_class[] = $second["sales_class_order"];
            $option_order[] = $second["option_order"];

        }
    }

array_multisort($sales_class, SORT_ASC, 
    $option_order, SORT_ASC,
    $array, 
    $keys);
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);
```